# Property 'first' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using ionic 2

I installed angular fire2

Version: `"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",`

I am getting this err

```
Property 'first' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'
```

I remove my nodemodules.

again npm install

Still getting same err.

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Read the "import only what you need by patching" section of the RxJS documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I install npm install @reactivex/rxjs.But i still get same err

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the first element in your **FirebaseListObservable< any[]>** in html file, then you can do like following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async | slice:0:1">{{item}}</div>
```

where "items" is **FirebaseListObservable< any[]>**

if you want to get the first element in your .ts file, then you should do like this:

```
firstItem: any;
...
this.items.subscribe((allItems) => {this.firstItem = allItems[0]});
```